# Encoding in python with lxml - complex solution

Tags: python, lxml

I need to download and parse webpage with lxml and build UTF-8 xml output. I think schema in pseudocode is more illustrative:

```
from lxml import etree

webfile = urllib2.urlopen(url)
root = etree.parse(webfile.read(), parser=etree.HTMLParser(recover=True))

txt = my_process_text(etree.tostring(root.xpath('/html/body'), encoding=utf8))


output = etree.Element("out")
output.text = txt

outputfile.write(etree.tostring(output, encoding=utf8))
```

So webfile can be in any encoding (lxml should handle this). Outputfile have to be in utf-8. I'm not sure where to use encoding/coding. Is this schema ok? (I cant find good tutorial about lxml and encoding, but I can find many problems with this...) I need robust solution.

Edit:

So for sending utf-8 to lxml I use

```
        converted = UnicodeDammit(webfile, isHTML=True)
        if not converted.unicode:
            print "ERR. UnicodeDammit failed to detect encoding, tried [%s]", \
                ', '.join(converted.triedEncodings)
            continue
        webfile = converted.unicode.encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

lxml can be a little wonky about input encodings.  It is best to send UTF8 in and get UTF8 out.

You might want to use the [chardet](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) module or [UnicodeDammit](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Beautiful%20Soup%20Gives%20You%20Unicode,%20Dammit) to decode the actual data.

You'd want to do something vaguely like:

```
import chardet
from lxml import html
content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
encoding = chardet.detect(content)['encoding']
if encoding != 'utf-8':
    content = content.decode(encoding, 'replace').encode('utf-8')
doc = html.fromstring(content, base_url=url)
```

I'm not sure why you are moving between lxml and etree, unless you are interacting with another library that already uses etree?

Comment: Unicode Dammit seems good. And about etree you are right, I've remove it from code.

Comment: Why not pass directly the decoded string (unicode object) to html.fromstring(), instead of re-encoding it to utf-8??

Comment: I can't remember what specifically was the motivation two and a half years ago, but I do vaguely remember that lxml didn't like Unicode input in some cases.  There's a very good chance that whatever that problem was it got fixed, so it's probably better to ignore that part now.  libxml2 (which powers lxml) does like UTF-8 input though, so if you were very performance sensitive you might want to avoid decoding that encoding in particular.

Answer (score 2):

lxml encoding detection is [weak](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#really-broken-pages).

> However, note that the most common problem with web pages is the lack
>   of (or the existence of incorrect) encoding declarations. It is
>   therefore often sufficient to only use the encoding detection of
>   BeautifulSoup, called UnicodeDammit, and to leave the rest to lxml's
>   own HTML parser, which is several times faster.

I recommend to detect encoding using **UnicodeDammit** and parse using **lxml**. 
Also, you can use http header **Content-Type** (you need to extract **charset=ENCODING_NAME**) to detect encoding more precisely.

For this example i'm using **BeautifulSoup4** (also you have to install **chardet** for better autodetection, because **UnicodeDammit uses chardet internally**):

```
from bs4 import UnicodeDammit

if http_charset == "":
    ud = UnicodeDammit(content, is_html=True)
else:
    ud = UnicodeDammit(content, override_encodings=[http_charset], is_html=True)
root = lxml.html.fromstring(ud.unicode_markup)
```

OR, to make previous answer more complete, you can modify it to:

```
if ud.original_encoding != 'utf-8':
    content = content.decode(ud.original_encoding, 'replace').encode('utf-8')
```

Why this is better than simple using chardet?

1. You do not ignore *Content-Type* HTTP header

   Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
2. You do not ignore **http-equiv** meta tag. Example:

   ... http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" ...
3. On top of this, you are using power of **chardet**, **cjkcodecs** and **iconvcodec** codecs and [many more](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Beautiful%20Soup%20Gives%20You%20Unicode,%20Dammit).