# chardet run incorrect in python 3

Tags: python, encoding, python-3.x, chardet

I am using chardet 2.01 in python 3.2，the souce code like this site http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/case-study-porting-chardet-to-python-3.html

can download here 
http://jaist.dl.sourceforge.net/project/cygwin-ports/release-2/Python/python3-chardet/python3-chardet-2.0.1-2.tar.bz2

I use lxml2 to parse html to get some string 
,and use below code to detect the encoding

```
chardet.detect(name)
```

But an error occurs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\test.py", line 125, in <module>
    print(chardet.detect(str(name)))
  File "E:\Python32\lib\site-packages\chardet\__init__.py", line 24, in detect
    u.feed(aBuf)
  File "E:\Python32\lib\site-packages\chardet\universaldetector.py", line 98, in feed
    if self._highBitDetector.search(aBuf):
TypeError: can't use a bytes pattern on a string-like object
```

`name` is a string object
Convert the string to bytes means encoding it with encoding like 'utf-8','big5'
 and so on,charset would detect the encoding you made....not the original string's encoding
I have no idea with this problem...

Comment: Why are you calling `str()` on something without knowing its encoding already?

Comment: What's in your `name` object? It should not be `b'something'` but rather just `'something'` - a string.

Comment: yes,'name' is a string object.But, if I convert it to bytes, I must encoding it ....lead the chardet.detect to become no use

Comment: @eternalblaze: a Python 3 `str` doesn't have an encoding; it's a sequence of unicode characters. It only makes sense to talk about the what encoding a `bytes` object is using.

Comment: I just want everyone understand I want to detect string object...

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\test.py", line 125, in <module>
    print(chardet.detect(bytes(name)))
TypeError: string argument without an encoding`<br>Convert the string means encoding it,`charset` would detect the encoding you made....not the original string's encoding

Comment: You may want to read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @Wooble: Is there anyway to reverse a string to original bytes?

Comment: Not without knowing what encoding it was in before you decoded it in the first place.

Comment: And also http://bit.ly/unipain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is obvious, you're calling `chardet` on a string rather than a bytes object. What you're missing is that to Python, a string **is already decoded**. It doesn't *have* an encoding anymore.

You must fix your code so that it's giving `chardet` the original bytes before they were decoded into a string. If you're getting the string from another package then it has already determined the encoding and there's nothing you can do.

Comment: But why chardet run correctly in python 2.x ?<br>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686709/encoding-in-python-with-lxml-complex-solution<br>

Comment: @eternalblaze: the example you link to doesn't try to detect the encoding of an already decoded string, but rather the encoding of the original bytestring (which, somewhat confusingly, is a `str` in python 2).

Comment: @eternalblaze, Python 2 doesn't differentiate between a string and an unencoded bytestring. Python 3 is a lot more strict, and now requires you to know the difference. You need to track which type you have and who's doing the conversions.